# Bokeh Div Text Size

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh

How do I change the text size inside a single bokeh Div widget without changing the text size of other Divs in my app? (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.markups.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Div takes a style argument in which you can put a dictionary filled with normal html styling, eg:

```
some_div = Div(text="<b>A Title</b>", style={'font-size': '200%', 'color': 'blue'})
```

Comment: argument name changed to styles (plural) since Bokeh 3.X

Answer (score 1):

In case of use of a bokeh server, you can also use css_classes = [] to add CSS class with definition in your css file

```
some_div = Div(text="<b>A Title</b>", css_classes=["my_div", "custom_css_class"])
```