# change color of python bokeh PreText()

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there a way to change the font or the color of

bokeh.models.widgets.markups.PreText

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import PreText
from bokeh.plotting import show

mytext = PreText()
mytext.text = "Text in black"
show(mytext)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bokeh markups are mapped to HTML elements, therefore you can bind style to it through the keyword `style`. Like this:

`mytext = PreText(text="Text in black", style={'color': 'black'})`

Also notice that the `PreText` maps to the `<pre>` tag which is used for pre formatted text, normally used to display code, for example. Depending on what you want do display, Paragraph would be more appropriate.

You may check the [documentation here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.markups.html#bokeh.models.widgets.markups.PreText) and also a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988808/bokeh-div-text-size) of using Bokeh and applying style.

Comment: great thanks! As it's an interactive color change the style flag was what I was searching for.